# How to discuss my unexpected experimental results?

Tags: phrase-requests, writing-style, research

In my research, I found that my proposed scheme does not provide very "high performance" gains as compared to the conventional scheme I was testing against.

Still, my results are better and I am submitting them to a conference. How can I rephrase the following in an apt manner?

> Here, we would like to mention that this increase is lower than our
>   initial expectation.

Comment: There are many ways to express the idea. The one you have suggested is OK.  Unless you give some guidance as to what idea, other than the basic fact, you wish to convey, we have nothing to base advice on.  Do you wish to say "We were so wrong!" or "We had hoped for more"?

Comment: I mean to say, "We had hoped for more"

Answer (score 1):

It sounds fine to me. I might suggest adding a few additional words - "*but is still significant nevertheless*". It gives direction to the ultimate idea you are trying to convey.

> Here, we would like to mention that this increase is lower than our
>   initial expectation, **but is still significant nevertheless**.

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/nevertheless

Answer (score 0):

I am going to drift a little away with this link to your question, but I thought it could be useful or wide-eye open to you. [replication crisis](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DEZl0e0J9rs)

I hesitate if `significant` is the right word since it must imply a statistic calculus and it means the variables have a certain correlation either positive or negative.

I would just say:

> as soon as the scheme is amended the performance is lower. (that has to have an explanation).